# Kinect depth image flickering when processed using Parallel.For

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm converting depth data from the Kinect into an image (Bgr565 format). When I iterate through the array of depth pixels (to map them to a color) using a standard for loop, i get a good smooth image. But when I use Parallel.For, I get a flickering image.

Here's the code sections. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
// === Single-threaded depth to color conversion ===
        for (int i = 0; i < depthPixelsArray.Length; ++i)
        {
            depth = (short)(depthPixelsArray[i] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth);
            if (depth >= colorBoundary)
                unchecked { colorPixelsArray[i] = (short)0xF800; }
            else colorPixelsArray[i] = depth;
        }

// === Multi-threaded depth to color conversion ===
 Parallel.For (0, depthPixelsArray.Length, delegate(int i)
            {
                depth = (short)(depthPixelsArray[i] >> DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmaskWidth);
                if (depth >= colorBoundary)
                    unchecked { colorPixelsArray[i] = (short)0xF800; }
                else colorPixelsArray[i] = depth;
            }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that this could happen if you're rendering them while the parallel processing is going on. In the single-threaded case, the rendering and the processing are probably sequential operations so it all looks good. When you call Parallel.For all you get back is a [ParallelLoopResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult.aspx) but the loop isn't completed yet. Rendering this still-processing result might be the cause of your flicker. You'll need to make sure [IsCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopresult.iscompleted.aspx) on the result is set before proceeding to render.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I did that (making sure IsCompleted is set) in my debugging. The image still flickers. I added this statement "while (!parallelLoopRes.IsCompleted) { };" before my rendering operation just to ensure that the parallel operation was completing.

Comment: Ok - I wasn't sure if you did that or not. Hmmm ... let's see. Could you post a couple of images showing the "flicker" ?

Comment: unfortunately, i'm not allowed to post images yet (not enough reputation points). But I think i've got an insight into the cause of the issue. It might be the image format i'm using to create the bitmap (Bgr565). I used Parallel.For in one of the sdk samples which uses BGR32 for depth to color conversion and there's no obswervable flicker on the image. I'll update my code and update this post later with the results.

Comment: Never mind. Image format is not the issue. I still haven't figure it out. You can see what the flickering looks like here: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/UMES3U21-WCFS7SGARSkgilXeiyRZUyvT3Gpb1LzYpY?feat=directlink and https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/bNJgDjDi6P89i4ovWXZgKylXeiyRZUyvT3Gpb1LzYpY?feat=directlink

Comment: The horizontal (and sloping) nature of the noise suggests to me that it might have something to do with stride inside the image. Are you taking that into account?

Comment: I used Parallel.Invoke() as well, splitting the arrays into equal chunks. No stride. Still the same result.

Comment: Does this happen if you something relatively simple - like offset & clamp or threshold the values? In other words - is this related to what you're doing or just a symptom when you use Parallel.For?

Comment: From all the troubleshooting I've done so far, it seems to be happening solely as a result of processing the depth array in parallel. I'm also doing other operations in parallel (such as obstacle detection, SLAM, etc...), so I'm wondering if/how this is affecting the result of those computations as well...